# Network unlocking under Android 2.3

Tags: mobile-network

Samsung SGH-I577. Got the unlock code! Yay!

Issue is that the network lock screen doesn't show up. At all. Tried with non att sims, the phone says the sim isn't inserted (which... no?).

Is there anything else I can try? The phone is stuck at android 2.3 and I can't update the phone to the ICS stock rom because of link rot.

I thought I could try the dialer codes I found on gsmhosting but with my code slipped in. No luck.

The AT Hayes modem doesn't recognize hardly any expanded command sets.

Dialing "*#7465625#" results in a broken screen.

Any help please? It would be COOL to network unlock this phone, even if it's pointless! (No VoLTE)